# Slack sends invalid, mal-formed JSON data after Dialog interaction

Tags: php, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-dialog

I am working on a slash command that'll invoke a dialog.

```
 $dialog = [
        'callback_id' => 'ryde-46e2b0',
        'title' => 'Request a Ride',
        'submit_label' => 'Request',
        'elements' => [
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Pickup Location',
                'name' => 'loc_origin'
            ],
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Dropoff Location',
                'name' => 'loc_destination'
            ]
        ]
    ];

    // get trigger ID from incoming slash request
    $trigger = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "trigger_id");

    // define POST query parameters
    $query = [
        'token' => 'XXXXXXXXX MY TOKEN XXXXXXXXX',
        'dialog' => json_encode($dialog),
        'trigger_id' => $trigger
    ];

    // define the curl request
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://slack.com/api/dialog.open');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    // set the POST query parameters
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($query));

    // execute curl request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // close
    curl_close($ch);

    var_export($response);
```

When I issue the slash command, my test dialog opens successfully

[image]

I then fill two test values `test1` and `test2` in the fields and submit the request. My endpoint is being hit with the dialog data payload correctly, but the data sent is not valid JSON:

The value of `$_POST` is: (I've masked all identifying tokens/IDs with xxx)

```
{"payload":"{\\\"type\\\":\\\"dialog_submission\\\",\\\"token\\\":\\\"XXX\\\",\\\"action_ts\\\":\\\"1536603864.688426\\\",\\\"team\\\":{\\\"id\\\":\\\"xxx\\\",\\\"domain\\\":\\\"ourdomain\\\"},\\\"user\\\":{\\\"id\\\":\\\"xxx\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"my_name\\\"},\\\"channel\\\":{\\\"id\\\":\\\"xxx\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"directmessage\\\"},\\\"submission\\\":{\\\"loc_origin\\\":\\\"test1\\\",\\\"loc_destination\\\":\\\"test2\\\"},\\\"callback_id\\\":\\\"ryde-46e2b0\\\",\\\"response_url\\\":\\\"https:\\\\/\\\\/hooks.slack.com\\\\/app\\\\/XXX\\\\/XXX\\\\/XXX\\\",\\\"state\\\":\\\"\\\"}"}
```

This is an invalid JSON, even when the "\\" instances are removed. Why is this happening?

Here is the code that handles the POST from Slack:

```
error_log(" -- dialog response: " . json_encode($_POST) . "\n", 3, './runtime.log');
```

Which results in the output above.

Comment: `payload` is a json string itself, so it needs to be escaped. I don't know why they do it this way, but... it also looks like a sideffect of the dead addslashes() behavior in older PHP. Weird issue you have here.

Comment: I'm on version PHP 7.1

Comment: @JasonGenX, can you show the code that accepts the post data? Based on [the documentation](https://api.slack.com/dialogs#evaluating_submission_responses), what you are showing does not look like what Slack should be sending.

Comment: simple. error_log(" -- dialog response: " . json_encode($_POST) . "\n", 3, './runtime.log');  this brings out the weird JSON format I've shown above.

Comment: In the future, when someone asks for additional information you should edit it into your question, not add it as a comment. I've done that for you in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are calling `json_encode($_POST)`. [The documentation](https://api.slack.com/dialogs#evaluating_submission_responses) is very clear on the format that will be sent:

```
$payload = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'payload');
$decoded = json_decode($payload);

var_dump($decoded);
```

Comment: Yep. That one did it. `filter_input` was the thing I was missing. I was calling $_POST directly just for debugging purposes after experiencing the JSON weirdness. I wanted to check the 'source' for my data. In any case-- thanks for your help.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `$_POST`. You were calling `json_encode()` on POST data. That POST data contained JSON. That is why the JSON appeared to be double escaped.